# JAXB XML to Pojo using inheritance how to

Tags: java, inheritance, jaxb, unmarshalling, pojo

I receive some XMLs from some endpoints. The basic structure of each response is similar (I get XML, no xsd):

1. Endpoint Name-Address

```
<RESPONSE>
<INFO>
  <ret_code>0</ret_code>
  </details>
</INFO>
<CONTENT>
   <name>John</name>
   <addresses>
      <address>
         <city>NewYork</city>
         <street>5th</street>
      </address>
      <address>
          <city>Paris</city>
          <street>Colombe</street>
      </address>
   </addresses>
</CONTENT>
</RESPONSE>
```

2. Endpoint for Salary

```
<RESPONSE>
<INFO>
  <ret_code>1</ret_code>
  <details>no salary data</details>
</INFO>
</RESPONSE>
```

or a valid response with data

```
<RESPONSE>
<INFO>
  <ret_code>0</ret_code>
  </details>
</INFO>
<CONTENT>
   <name>John</name>
   <salary>1000</salary>
</CONTENT>
</RESPONSE>
```

3. Common parts

As you can see the <RESPONSE> tag is always there and the <INFO> tag is always there. The <CONTENT> is not always present and sometimes the content varies based on which endpoint is called.

So I wanted to (using JaxB) map these to some POJO as follows:

1. INFO class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="INFO")
public class INFO {
    @XmlElement
    public String ret_code;
    @XmlElement 
    public String details;
}
```

Also an ADDRESS class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "address")
public class ADDRESS{
    @XmlElement
    public String city;
    @XmlElement
    public String street;
}
```

2. EndpointAddress

```
@XmlRootElement(name="RESPONSE")
public class Response extends INFO{

    @XmlElement(name="name")
    public String name;

    @XmlWrapperElement(name="addresses")
    @XmlElement(name="address")
    public List<Address> addresses;
}
```

2.1.) EndpointAddress variation without inheritance

```
@XmlRootElement(name="RESPONSE")
public class Response {
 
    @XmlElement(name="INFO")
    public INFO info; 

    @XmlElement(name="name")
    public String name;

    @XmlWrapperElement(name="addresses")
    @XmlElement(name="address")
    public List<Address> addresses;
}
```

3. Endpoint Salary - 2 cases here (inheritance or not) as above.. will not post both to keep it short

```
@XmlRootElement(name="RESPONSE")
public class Response extends INFO{

    @XmlElement(name="salary")
    public String salary;
}
```

At this point the mapping returns:

1. ClassCastException trying to map INFO into Response when using inheritance
2. null values for  Info info, addresses when no inheritance.

Any help on how to achieve some reusability would be more than welcomed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have a possible solution that you can download from [hisrc-higherjaxb-sample-any-content-2.1.0-mvn-src.zip](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/releases/download/2.1.0/hisrc-higherjaxb-sample-any-content-2.1.0-mvn-src.zip). The download is a standalone Maven project containing a unit test to parse your `RESPONSE` files using JAXB generated classes from [response.xsd](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/any-content/src/main/resources/response.xsd), a reverse engineered XML schema.

*Solution:*

Create an XML Schema by inspecting the XML to identify this structure:

```
CONTENT: anySimpleType
CONTENTAddress: complexType
CONTENTSalary: complexType
RESPONSE: complexType
    INFO: complexType
    CONTENT: ref
```

The key is to define the `CONTENT` as `anySimpleType` and as a top level element. As such, JAXB is able to unmarshal the ambiguous content (address, salary, etc.) into a general DOM `Element`. Further, as a top-level element, JAXB treats it as a root element that can be marshaled into an XML fragment.

The trick is to programmatically detect the actual type from the fragment then modify the fragment to use the correct `CONTENT` tag: CONTENTAddress, CONTENTSalary, etc. Then to unmarshal the modified XML to instantiate the final objects.